# Intergrating C#(VS2010) and Unity Engine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a virtual tour using unity engine which will interact with the user using a web camera. I'm using Open CV for digital imagine and C#(Visual Studio 2010) as my programming language(The virtual tour will run inside a c# program). I want to know, is it possible to integrate unity engine with Visual studio 2010?? If its possible, please give me some resources like tutorials. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to enter to this site and read the second answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25671/how-to-set-visual-studio-2010-as-default-script-ed.html

Comment: He is asking how to INTEGRATE Unity3d scene in a C# project not how to use VS as a Unity3d scripts editor.

Comment: Valentin Simonov - That is correct i'd be grateful if one could give me some help here.